# How to print and read at in the same line in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im comming from C++.

This code:

```
 int main() {
     int age; 
     std::cout << "Type your age: ";
     std::cin  >> age;
     return 0;
 }
```

Would produce something like this on terminal:

```
 Type your age: _
```

I can enter the age value on the same line of the message.

How can I achieve the same result in Haskell?

Comment: What Haskell code did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IO happens out of order when using getLine and putStr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190314/io-happens-out-of-order-when-using-getline-and-putstr)

Comment: I would not turn off buffering, as the answers below propose, but instead run `hFlush stdout` after the message is printed, to be sure all the buffers are pushed to the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `putStr` function to print message without newline at the end as:

```
import System.IO

main = do hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
          putStr "Type your age: "
          age <- readLn::IO Int
          return ()
```

Answer (score 3):

By default output is written to a buffer until there's a newline and only then actually written to stdout. To disable the buffer and just write directly to stdout you want to run `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`. (The relevant bindings are found in System.IO)